# Finale or Sibelius on Ubuntu 11.10 under Wine?

Tags: software-recommendation, wine

I want to install either Finale 2011-2012 or Sibelius 5-6-7 on my 11.10 install via Wine. Before I purchase any of them, does anyone know if they work on Wine 1.4 (or even 1.5) on 11.10? I've seen some posts on the Winehq about those programs, but they are on older Wine releases on older Ubuntu releases with older versions of software.

Also, I'm not the biggest fan of MuseScore...if anyone knows of any native programs for Linux that as powerful as Finale or Sibelius, could anyone let me know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AppDB doesn't have a recent entry for either. That's what I would have suggested first. Support on older versions is all over the place. It's impossible to say how well they'll work for you based on those reviews.

But then I saw that both applications offer 30-day trial licenses. Try them both!

---

On a related note, I saw [this thread](http://linuxmusicians.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=715) on [Linux Musicians](http://linuxmusicians.com). While it's not a current thread it does look like a great forum for people making music on Linux.